# how to get filtered related code with Gorm in Go lang

Tags: go, go-gorm

`Db.Preload("Category").Where("events.categories.id = ?", 1).Find(&events)`

This is my code, I'd like to get event of data only category id 1.

Please let me know how to use where with Preload.

Comment: Have you tried to [read the docs](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Preload-with-conditions) before posting a qurstion to SO?

Comment: Do you want to preload only categories with id=1 for all events that are returned or do you want to return just events that are linked to the category with id=1?

Comment: I'd like to return just events that are linked to the category with id=1.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get relational data with bellow code.

```
    Db.Table("events").
        Select("events.*, categories.name, categories.slug").
        Joins("INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = events.category_id").
        Where("events.category_id = ?", "1").
        Scan(&events)
```

And we have to make struct and use Select when we use Joins.

```
type EventJoinsCategory struct {
    Event
    Category
}
```

Thank you.